# How to Remove the link from featured image?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I don't have enough knowledge about PHP to handle this situation. What I want is to remove the link from featured image. Here is the code from my functions.php file.

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {       
        return "<div class='post-thumbnail'><a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>" . $featured_image . "</a></div>";      
    }
```

Could you please tell me which part should I erase to get the desired result??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this :)

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {       
    return "<div class='post-thumbnail'>" . $featured_image . "</div>";      
}
```

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot. I was confused about the dots(.). I wasn't sure which one to delete and which one to keep.

Comment: You're more than welcome! You just have to remove the hrefs `"<a href='" . $featured_image_link . "'>"` and `"</a>"`. The dots just join everything together when it's displayed to the user.